# Explain this boiling point order please

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

I read it from a book but don't know the reason. Please explain...

Boiling point orders are -

**Ethanamide > Ethanoic Anhydride > Ethanoic Acid**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ethanamide has a higher boiling point than ethanoic acid since amide has two hydogen atoms it can form more Hydrogen bonds than ethanoic acid and their molar masses are 45gmol-1 and 60gmol-1 which makes the difference brought by the London forces somewhat negligible .
you may suppose Ethanoic anhydride should be having a lower boiling point than ethanoic acid and ethanamide since it only has London forces and dipole dipole attractions.But ehanoic anhydride(molar mass-106gmol-1) has a higher molar mass than Ethanoic acid(molar mass-60gmol-1) making the London forces in ehatnoic anhydride more significant.
Hence we have 
ethanamide(222 °C)>Ethanoic anhydride(140°C)>Ethanoic acid(118°C).

Comment: My book says, Ethanoic Anhydride molecular mass is much more than Ethanoic Acid, that's why Ethanoic Anhydride have higher boiling point than Ethanoic Acid. I have rather more confusion that why ethanamide have higher boiling point than Ethanoic Anhydride.

Comment: Yes Helena your book is correct and I have revised my answer.Hope it helps.